# SQL Query pull top 1 value for each type from the list?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the table in my Database with different type for each product. I want to pull the top 1 record for each product based on that type. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    dh_type, 
    dh_product
FROM myProducts
WHERE dh_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0'
    AND dh_type IN ('New','Old','Ref')
ORDER BY dh_createDt DESC
```

Each type can have multiple products that have been created on the different date. I want to pull the top record (the most recent based on the create date) for each type. One for New, one for Old and one for Ref. I was wondering what is the best and most efficient way to do that in SQL? Current query will pull more than one record for each type and I need only one.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to get what you want one way is by using a windowing function like `row_number()`. The [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function allows you to create a unique number for each row with a partition, in your case the partition is by `dh_type` and then order the creation of the the number by your `dh_createDT`. The final result would then be the rows with a row_number = 1.:

```
select dh_type, 
      dh_product
from
(
  SELECT 
      dh_type, 
      dh_product,
      rn = row_number() over(partition by dh_type order by dh_createDT desc)
  FROM myProducts
  WHERE dh_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0'
      AND dh_type IN ('New','Old','Ref')
) d
where rn = 1;
```

Another way to get the result would be to use a subquery that gets the `max(dh_createDT)` for each `dh_type` and `dh_product`, then join that back to your table:

```
select 
  dh_type,
  dh_product
from myProducts p
inner join
(
  select 
    dh_type, 
    dh_product,
    MaxDate = max(dh_createDT)
  from myProducts
  where h_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0'
    and dh_type IN ('New','Old','Ref') 
  group by dh_type, dh_product
) p1
  on p.dh_type = p1.dh_type
  and p.dh_product = p1.dh_product
  and p.dh_createDT = p1.MaxDate
where p.h_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0'
  and p.dh_type IN ('New','Old','Ref')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ollie has a really good answer.  However, if performance is the issue, then the following may be faster:

```
(SELECT TOP (1) dh_type, dh_product
 FROM myProducts
 WHERE dh_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0' AND dh_type = 'New'
 ORDER BY dh_createDt DESC
) UNION ALL
(SELECT TOP (1) dh_type, dh_product
 FROM myProducts
 WHERE dh_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0' AND dh_type = 'Old'
 ORDER BY dh_createDt DESC
) UNION ALL
(SELECT TOP (1) dh_type, dh_product
 FROM myProducts
 WHERE dh_productid = '08-BLD4011603S0' AND dh_type = 'Ref'
 ORDER BY dh_createDt DESC
);
```

For performance, you want an index on `myProducts(dh_productid, dh_type, dh_createDt)`.  You might as well through in `dh_product` as well, so the index fully covers the query.